# Input-type range with custom css - thumb not showing correct in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input, range

My web page looks good in all other browsers than IE. Here the thumb of my range sliders are "cut off".

My code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/t1pw9rh2/

HTML:

```
<form action="url-link-here" method="post">

<span id="mydiv">100</span>

<input class="input-range" id="sizeID" onchange="test()" oninput="test()" type="range" name="size" value="100" min="5" max="250" step ="5">

</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
  height: 28px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #fff;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
  height: 28px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
  border: 1px solid #39404D;
  height: 28px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #fff;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function test(){
var myDivElem = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var sizerange= document.getElementById("sizeID");
myDivElem.innerHTML = sizerange.value;
}
```

My web page can be seen here:

http://negoto.azurewebsites.net/

How do I fix the css so the thumb looks good in IE?

Best, Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here. http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html
It mentions you cant style the thumb bigger than the track in IE.